# Can getauxval be wrapped and used with LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, ld-preload

I have a C file inside it has two very small subs that reimplement getauxval,

```
unsigned long int __wrap_getauxval (unsigned long int __type) {
  printf("foobar");
  exit(5);
}

unsigned long int getauxval (unsigned long int __type) {
  printf("foobar");
  exit(5);
}
```

I'm compiling this with

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -ldl -Wl,-wrap=getauxval hax.c -o hax.so
```

Like that, I can run this

```
LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/hax.so myExec
```

And it'll print `foobar` and die, but **if I remove `getauxval`** and rely on only the LD -wrap'd version `__wrap_getauxval`, I see it doesn't work. What am I missing here? How come I can re-implement `getauxval` and `LD_PRELOAD`, but I can't wrap it? And what do I do to wrap a function like `getauxval`?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to store a function pointer

```
static unsigned long int (*real_getauxval)(unsigned long int __type) = NULL;
```

And, then to use `dlsym` to retrieve the symbol dynamically

```
real_getauxval = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "getauxval");
```

I was then able to easily wrap `getauxval`